# How to get the absolute path of installer package inside package maker?

Tags: macos, packagemaker, pkg-file

During installation, I want to get the the absolute path of current installer package (created using package maker).

So that i can able to read the value of plist file(Located in same package path) inside post/pre install scripts during package installation.

So anyone please provide the solution to get the the absolute path of current installer package.

Answer (score 1):

There are some environment variables you can use from inside the pre/postinstall script to get the paths. They are explained in this blog post: http://www.macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html